# How to set parent for list of json object

Tags: java, json

My current json is,

```
[
    {
       "date":"2013-11-19",
       "time":"10:30",
    },
    {
       "date":"2013-11-19",
       "time":"12:20",
    }
 ]
```

I need to set the parent for the above list of json objects like the following,

```
"results":{[
             {
                "date":"2013-11-19",
                "time":"10:30",
             },
             {
                "date":"2013-11-19",
                "time":"12:20",
             }
          ]
    }
```

The following code not working for me,

```
> JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
>     obj.put("results", new JSONArray(list));
```

How to set the parent for the list of object?
Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: Looks like you already achieved your result? I don't see the problem?

Comment: No, I didn't get.. If i set with JSONObject it returns  "results":{ "names": { [
             {
                "date",
                "time",
             },
             {
                "date",
                "time"
             }
          ] }
    }

Comment: And what is wrong with that? It seems to be exactly the output you want.

Comment: @Ben it didn't return the key value pair, It only returns the key.. I need both

Comment: Then add it? I mean, it sounds like you could just open your JSON in notepad, add *"results":{* in front of it and *}* to the back of it. Why do you delete the values?

Comment: I just edited for giving you the sample.. but in my project getting the same.. :(

Comment: I am sorry. At this point I have literally zero ideas what you are doing. You have some file. You want to edit the file. You open it in your editor of choice, edit it and you are done. Could you please explain which step is not working? Also this seems to be more related to... tech support probably, it does not have anything to do with programming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172050/discussion-between-sst-and-ben).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jackson for this. Here is the sample

```
    String s = "[\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "       \"date\":\"2013-11-19\",\n" +
            "       \"time\":\"10:30\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "       \"date\":\"2013-11-19\",\n" +
            "       \"time\":\"12:20\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            " ]";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode array = mapper.readTree(s);
    JsonNode result = mapper.createObjectNode().set("result", array);
    System.out.println(result);
```

The ouptut is

```
{"result":[{"date":"2013-11-19","time":"10:30"},{"date":"2013-11-19","time":"12:20"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set using JsonObject class in Java.

for example you have this JsonArray

```
[
    {
       "date":"2013-11-19",
       "time":"10:30",
    },
    {
       "date":"2013-11-19",
       "time":"12:20",
    }
 ]`
```

so you need to create JsonArray object from that json array result then create an another JsonObject to hold this array .like below

```
try{
   JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(<your json array string>);
   JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
   root.put("results", arr); //putting json array in root json object with results key.

}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if you do `root.toString()` you'll get the json as you expected.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its not working.. it returns {
  "results": [
    {
      "names": [
        "date",
        "time"
      ],
      "empty": false
    },
    {
      "names": [
        "date",
        "time"
      ],
      "empty": false
    }
  ]
}

Comment: check your json array, are you sure you are getting correct json array?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jayanth!! But its not working for me.. :(

Comment: It works fine, when I modify the code like s the following,                                                              JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(list.toString());
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
        result.put("results", arr);

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    {      "results":[
         {
            "date":"2013-11-19",
            "time":"10:30",
         },
         {
            "date":"2013-11-19",
            "time":"12:20",
         }
      ]
}
```